# How to print contents of register in c

Tags: c, pointers, cpu-registers

I'm trying to debug a driver that I'm writing for a UART that reads a string of `chars` from a serial console until the user press 'l'. The function is called 'getstring()' below.

I want to examine the contents of a status register to see which bits are set. The status register is offset by 2. I need to print it when 'getstring()' is called. I can use `printf()`.

This is the register map for the UART.

[image: Register_map]

When I call the How could I print out the contents of a register in `c`?

```
#define UART 0x00080000
void getchar(char *str) {

    volatile uint32_t *uart = (volatile uint32_t*) UART;

    char c = 0;
    do
    {
        while ((uart[2] & (1<<7)) == 0);
        c = uart[0];
        *str++ = c;
    }
    while (c!='l');
}
```

Comment: How exactly does `while (c!='l');` make any sense? You realize that it is a `L` and not a `1`, yes?

Comment: @Lundin thanks, yes I realise that is an 'l'. Read characters from RX buffer until the user presses 'l'. Appreciate your help. Kind regards

Comment: Usually registers' contents is printed in hexadecimal format, that is easy to read and compact at the same moment. Therefore, you could just use `%x` in `printf` to print the value (`printf("%x\n", *uart)`).

Comment: @scalauser Why are you deleting parts of your question? It no longer makes any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert from binary to an ASCII string of ones and zeroes, simply do this:

```
uint32_t local = *uart;
for(size_t i=0; i<32; i++)
{
  *str = (local & (1u << 31-i) ? '1' : '0';
  str++;
}
*str = '\0';
```

Comment: Hi @Lundin, I updated my original question, perhaps if you have some time you might take a look. Thank you

Comment: @scalauser If you have a different follow-up question, please don't edit the current one, but post a new question (with a link to this one if needed).

Comment: Repeatedly reading a device register in this situation is a very bad idea, as there is no guarantee that the register value will be constant during the 32 iterations. When another character is received, the contents of `str` will be bogus; i.e. a blend of more than one register value.

Comment: @sawdust That's very true actually, I was too focused on the algorithm to even consider that the source was a hardware register. Answer's been fixed.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <x86intrin.h> // Include for __rdtscp

 int get_value()
 {
      __asm__ (   "movl $20, %eax;"); 
 } 
 
 int main() 
 {
      printf("%d\n",get_value()); //read the value of eax register
                                  // that we store is 20 in the get value function
      return 0;
 }
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question in any way.